# How to watermark only original images?

Tags: javascript, image, watermark

I am trying to protect my website content by putting scripts to deny the right click and to see the source code in the browsers. But this is not sufficient. I want to know how to watermark only the original file and not the image that is seen on the webpage.

For example, an image that users can see on the web without watermark and when they click right and select "Open image in a new tab" they go to "website.com/image.png" and they see the watermarked image.

Is this possible?

P.S.: Sorry for my bad English, I'm not a good writer.

Thanks

Comment: "But this is not sufficient" or even reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serving users a image which is not watermarked is not a good idea because they can download it easily so the best way will be watermark every images and render it users by slicing it. Slice the image and show only the image and hide the water mark and whey they will open it in new window full image will be loaded with the water mark

For creating Watermark on the fly with php 
http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1147

And for slicing image i don't know how to do that but i know it is possible but there are many ways to do it like you can zoom it to hide watermarks.

Comment: So make a watermarked image and show on the web the same image but cropped? And when you go to the original file you see the watermark?

Comment: Yes , it is the only way i guess to show user an image without watermark but if they save/download it the whole image will be downloaded.. with watermark
For better cropping keep your watermark in end not in the middle.

Comment: And, can i crop all the images automatically, or I have to use a code on all the images?

Comment: Thanks for all, finally I used larger images and then with CSS crop them.

Comment: @newboyhun Yes yes, I put negative margin on the bottom, that crops the image, and the original is with the watermark.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this will not stop them from downloading the image without watermark, because they can disable javascript, or simply right click on the image and save it right there, or the worst: simply do a print screen and save it to paint then crop it. Probably the best option is to have watermark on all of your images, on the website and on the direct access.

Comment: Thanks for helping, that was the first option I thought, but in the web the images are in lower resolution and in Google I searched some images that you have to go to the original web to copy the images.

Comment: Well you can show the low resolution version to the user, but that's not a real solution. As i said, always use watermark, no other way.
Just think about 'print screen', there is no real solution to protect your images. They will always be able to steal it somehow, but atleast you can protect it from being the 'right' image with a watermark. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks ofr yout help, it will be the best and the easier solution to the problem :(